# php simplexml_load_file in a loop causes Fatal error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, xml

When I use simplexml_load_file to individual file, it works fine. However, since I have so many of them, when I tried to run my script to a batch of files.

In case this is relavant,  I have two kind of log files to load into my database. One starts with . The other starts with . (But looking at the error, the error occurs even w/ the same structure.)

```
<?php
$dir_path = ".";
if ($dir_handler = opendir($dir_path)) {
    while (($sub_dir = readdir($dir_handler)) !== false) {  //reading all sub dir
        if (is_dir($sub_dir)) {
            if (substr($sub_dir,0,6) == "201209") {     //filter only desired sub dir
                $sub_dir_handler = opendir($sub_dir);
                    while($file = readdir($sub_dir_handler)) { //reading files in each 
                                                               //qualified sub dir
                        if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..")) { //except . and ..
                            $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);   // got error on 
                                                                 //the second file
                            if ($xml->getname() != "hash") { // tried to distinct 
                                                            // structure type but error
```

Comment: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity 
//for openning the second file
Fatal error: Call to a member function getname() on a non-object 
//second error on the second file being read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess simplexml_load_file return false (error)
You can see those using libxml_get_errors, cf http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php

Edit:
Considering your 2nd comment, looks like your file is not accessible to SimpleXML...

Comment: Thank you haltabush...I thought I tried it individually and there was no problem with any. am under impression that I need to flush the content of $xml before I load another file to it. Will try on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Found the silly cause.

because I keep all files in the subdirs, I "need" to concat the subdir to the filename to locate the path. The error, thus, cause by cannot open file. It also explains why I can open it individually when I hard code the filename.

Since there is now no error, the libxml_get_error cannot be applied to my script.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Since I want to skip the second type of xml schema which causes the error I use

if (!libxml_get_errors())

to continue my work. Many many thank to you.